# Camomile and oregano stopped growing after sprouting

Tags: houseplants, growth, herbs

I planted oregano and camomile from seeds, and shortly after sprouting they stopped growing. I tried moving them to a more sunny or shaded areas, but they still don't grow. They keep being the same height for about a month now.

I keep them inside my house and water them regularly. What could prevent them from growing? Other plants in my house seem to be doing fine, just not these two. What could be the cause of that lack of growth?

[image: the camomile sprouts, still about 2cm in height]

[image: the oregano sprouts, still about 2cm in height]

Comment: What part of the world are you in?

Comment: I'm in Poland. It's winter here now

Answer (score 3):

The seedlings are quite etiolated - the high sides of the box they're in won't be helping that, but regardless,you need to keep them out of direct sunlight, they're too small to cope with that at this stage.

Given where you are, the fact that it's winter and daylight hours are short, that's most likely what the problem is, insufficient light. Seeds always grow stronger and faster in spring than they will at this time of year; many respond not only to temperature but also light levels and day length. You could try using a grow light to see if that helps them to at least produce a true set of leaves, at which point you can prick them out into individual pots,this time ensuring they're not planted too low.

Comment: As a beginner, it's not clear to me - direct sunlight is not ok, but a grow lamp is?

Comment: Yes - a grow light doesn't approximate sunlight, just daylight. Don't use it all night,  it's just to increase the number of daylight hours for the seedlings to about the length of a late spring day or early summer would have.

Comment: I'll try using the grower lamp and report on the results